# WPF radiobutton event handling questions

Tags: wpf, events

`radio.Checked += new RoutedEventHandler(VariantChecked);`
assuming I have this code. What if I want to pass an argument to VariantChecked method. What syntax should I apply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During creation, attach your data object to the DataContext or the Tag property of the RadioButton.

```
RadioButton radio=new RadioButton();
radio.DataContext=yourData;
```

Then in the event handler, get the data back:

```
void VariantChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){ 
   RadioButton  radio=(RadioButton)sender; 
   YourData yourData=(YourData)radio.DataContext; 
}
```

In the above example I have assumed that you have a class or struct named YourData that you want to provide. You can replace this through any primitive like string or int or any other object type.

---

The above works also from xaml:

```
<RadioButton Tag="Static Data, could also be a binding" ...
```

Here I have taken the Tag property because it makes for such a construction more sense, but DataContext could also be taken. The event handler is the same except for casting from the Tag-property.

```
void VariantChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){    
   RadioButton  radio=(RadioButton)sender;    
   string yourStringFromTag=(string)radio.Tag; 
}
```

---

By the way, you can make the code more generic by not specify a concrete control-class but a base class:

```
void VariantChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){    
   FrameworkElement fe=(FrameworkElement)sender;    
   string yourStringFromTag=(string)fe.Tag; 
}
```

Hope this helped...

Comment: How did you use Tag to attach a property in the last example? Is it possible to attach more than one object to it?

Comment: @Sergey: In the second example I did it via xaml. In the 3. example, I have not attached. The example is only to show that you don't have to cast to the concrete class but also can take a base-class. If you want to attach more than one object, declare a struct, a container class or use the Tuple-class (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx)